# Using Cross Apply in XQuery

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

This is my store to process get data:

```
(PromotionSetup.query(''
for $PS in Setup/Include[@Type = ''''Product'''']/Value[text()]                                     
where contains($PS, ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '_'''') or $PS = ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '''''
return data($PS)         
'')).value(''(.)'', ''nvarchar(max)'') as InfoProductPromotion
```

And, this is my result:

```
468908_3:2000; 468908_3:1000;
```

That result was compare 2 data in one line. So, i'm looking in the internet that using `cross apply` to detached data in 2 lines.

This is a result i want:

```
468908_3:2000; 
468908_3:1000;
```

Unfortunately, i can't imagine how to using cross apply into Xquery. Can someone can help me??

Answer (score 0):

Check this sql statement if it can help :

```
;WITH yourtable
     AS (SELECT '468908_3:2000; 468908_3:1000;' AS yourcolumn)

SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(c1.value('.', 'varchar(100)')))
FROM   (SELECT CAST('<N>' + REPLACE(yourcolumn, ';', ';</N><N>')
                    + '</N>' AS XML)
        FROM   yourtable) t(c)
       CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/N') AS t1(c1)
WHERE  RTRIM(LTRIM(c1.value('.', 'varchar(100)'))) <> ''
```

Comment: i mean that, when store run, it must be detached data in 2 line by customize query.